# How to model a torus in torus? Solidworks 2019

Tags: solidworks

[image: Equations of the torus]

This is for a personal project, I want to model this as a spline in solidworks but I don't know how, what equation should I use in the equation driven curve method? Or what would be the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an Equation driven curve.
You will need a 3Dsketch for your curve first.
Here is an example:
[image]

Where 10 is  the major radius

4 is the minor radius

using 12 winds

You can use dimensions also instead of numbers, just like you use equations.